# Блокировка окна при прокрутке мышкой

Tags: javascript

Привет!

Как сделать так, что бы после того как я один раз прокрутил колесико мышки, окно не реагировало на движения колесика, блокировалось так сказать. Такое ощущение, что если один раз прокрутить колесико мышки, происходит несколько событий. Вот простой пример: я хочу что бы окно всегда было в верху сайта.

```
var scrollHandler = function(e){
    $('html, body').scrollTop('0px');
    return false;
    }
$(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
```

Но, как видно, окошко сначала дергается, а только потом встает в нужную позицию.
Как от этого избавиться?

Comment: `$(window).one('scroll', scrollHandler);`

- [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

Answer (score 1):

Если убрать scroll, то колесо работать не будет вообще.

```
$("html").css("overflow","hidden");
```

Какая глобальная цель преследуется?

Comment: Сделать точно как здесь: http://community.saucony.com/kinvara3/ Ну только слайды у меня не во весь экран. 
При первом движении колесика все блокируется и начинается анимация, при этом можно спокойно таскать за скролл бар без аниации

Comment: там используется плагин [mousewheel][1]. С его помощью ловится первый поворот колеса, и пока идет анимация, дальнейшее кручение колеса блокируется, т.е. скроллинг выполняется в скрипте, предотвращая скроллинг браузера:

 $("body").bind("mousewheel", function (delta, aS, aQ, deltaY) {
  delta.preventDefault();
  if (deltaY > 0) {
   scrollPrev();
  } else {
   if (deltaY < 0) {
    scrollNext();
   }
  }
  return false;
 });

скрипт, в котором реализуется эта логика [здесь][2].

[1]:https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel
[2]:http://community.saucony.com/kinvara3/js/script.js

Comment: кстати если на этом сайте спрятать scroll как в моем ответе, то слайды также будут листаться, т.е. mousewheel событие возникает все равно.

Comment: да, скрипт я смотрел, но в каком месте там блокируется скроллинг я не понял. А что за функцию вы привели выше? что в ней за параметры?

Comment: это обработчик для события, которое вызывается плагином, изначально параметры колбэк-функции такие ``function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY)``. скроллинг бывает не только вертикальный, но и горизонтальный, плагин это тоже учитывает.

плагин ловит поворот колеса, если событие не перехватить и не перекрывать через preventDefault, то будет скроллинг браузера. а если перекрыть, то браузер не узнает, что колесо крутили. дальше уже наша работа, можем делать в принципе все что угодно, в частности листать слайды в сторону знака дельты.

Comment: Дружище! Ты спас меня.) Лучей добра тебе миллион))